# Is there any way to install direct 2.4 version of GWT plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, windows-8.1

In our project we are using GWT-2.4 version of GWT plugin. This plugin was already installed in eclipse which will support for Windows XP-32 bit in long back.

But, recently I got a new system with Windows 8.1 - 64 bit. When I tried to install GWT plugin in JUNO/LUNA, by default it is installing GWT-2.6 version. This will be not supported in my project.

If is there any way to install GWT-2.4 version of GWT plugin in eclipse, please reply on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the SDK version?

If yes, download the SDK from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/versions.html).

Unpack the SDK.

Goto Preferences -> Google -> Web Toolkit

Select the Add button and choose the recently downloaded version.

Comment: Hi Hoss, thanks for your reply. I am not asking about the SDK. I need plugin in eclipse. When I have tried to install GWT plugin for eclipse by default it is downloading gwt-plugin-2.6. I want to install gwt-plugin-2.4.

Comment: Here you'll find older versions of the plugin: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download_older Hope that helps.